# Getting thread ID from parallel package

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a simple shared memory code `helloworld.R` code :

```
library(parallel)
nCores <- detectCores()
v<-character(length=nCores)
tid<-someFuncToGetThreadID()     # <---What function to use here?
v<-mclapply(v,function(x) x=sprintf("Hello World from thread : %i",tid))
```

How do I get the thread ID (`tid`) for each thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are forked *processes* not threads. You can use `Sys.getpid()` to get the process IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was imagining it more like a thread in OpenMP.

Answer (score 1):

You may try assigning IDs yourself.

```
clusterApply(cl, 1:cluster_num, function(x){
    tid <<- x
})
```

For example,

```
library(parallel)
ncluster <- 5
cl <- makeCluster(ncluster)
clusterApply(cl,1:ncluster, function(x){
    tid <<- x
})
v<-clusterCall(cl, function(){sprintf("Hello World from thread :%d",tid)})
stopCluster(cl)
```